# Name of this argumentation

Tags: argumentation

Scenario 1: Suppose Person A talks about some historical event X-Y and claims that it can only be a miracle. (Miracle taken as literally.) Person B rejects, saying that X-Y has a  natural explanation.

Scenario 2: Suppose Person A talks about some historical event W-Z and claims that it can only be a miracle. Person B rejects, saying that the existence of W-Z is unverified.

Does Person B's argumentation has a name?

EDIT: I am more like whether Person B's attitude of bad argument has a name, like the examples in https://bookofbadarguments.com/

Comment: You might call it *dogmatism*.

Comment: These are two different cases. In one, Person B agrees that the event happened--say, an earthquake--but claims to have an alternate, valid interpretation of the event based on natural causes. In case two, Person B is claiming that there is insufficient evidence to support the claim that the event even happened. In general, Person B appears to be generally skeptical as opposed to credulous, but being generally skeptical is not unique to a given form of argument or philosophical position.

Answer (score 2):

The way the cases are set up, it’s not clear to me that **B** advances *any* argument at all. In the first scenario, **A** makes a twofold claim:

(1.1) Event XY happened.

(1.2) All XY-type events are miracles.

The conclusion is that a miracle happened. Now, **B** responds by rejecting (1.2) – and a rejection of a premise/claim isn’t in itself an argument. Of course, **B** may support her move by providing a natural explanation for XY; but providing an explanation also isn’t in itself an argument.

If there is an argument here, it would be a *meta-theoretic* argument, to the effect that natural explanations are in some sense *better* than explanations that reference miracle. What the meta-theoretic argument is exactly, would depend on the details of the case. It may be an instance of Ockham’s Razor; but it may also have to do with the fact that natural explanations have more predictive power, are simpler, can be tested, …

In the second scenario, **A** makes the same twofold claim as before (except we’re talking of WZ and not XY). Yet this time, **B** responds by rejecting the first part of the claim, rather than the second. Once again, a rejection isn’t in itself an argument. As before, **B** may support her move – say by pointing out that the historical sources that speak of WZ are unreliable.

This *could* again be interpreted as a meta-theoretic argument: assuming that the sources are unreliable, is theoretically *better* (whatever that means exactly) than accepting that a miracle occurred.

Now, there is a slightly simpler (and much less detailed) way to look at the situation. It seems that **B** firmly accepts the following claim:

(3) There are no miracles.

In turn, if you combine (3) with (1.2), it *logically follows* that (1.1) is false. Likewise, if you combine (3) with (1.1), it logically follows that (1.2) is false. The first implication is an instance of *modus tollens*, the second could just about count as a *reductio ad absurdum*.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what someone else said, that the "bad argument" here could be described as "dogmatism".

Person A's bad argument, that is.

Person B could be described as "disagreeing" with Person A's assertions, to which Person A then puts their fingers in their ears and says "la la la".

Someone else said that person B does not give any argument at all, which I disagree with.

I suggest that Person B is arguing that 1 or more of Person A's assertions are false, which can be described as "disagreeing" with those assertions.